# How to setup subdomain for digitalocean?

Tags: dns, subdomain, digital-ocean

I need to access my Digitalocean server by typing sendy.ambee.app in the URL. If I type the IP address 157.230.9.219, it works.

[image]

But as long as I type sendy.ambee.app, it does NOT work.

[image]

When I `ping sendy.ambee.app` in terminal, it pings the correct IP address (157.230.9.219). Same thing when I try it here https://asm.saas.broadcom.com/en/ping.php

This is my Google domain's Name Space settings:
[image]

Shall I change `Name servers`? Just note here, on my ambee.app domain I use Google Workspace (so I do want to keep google servers for the main domain)

What else shall I have set up in there (in Google Domains DNS settings)? This is what I got so far:
[image]

I'm confused about many options there

- shall I add A record in `Custom resource records`
- or shall I forward sendy.ambee.app → 157.230.9.219 in `Synthetic records`
- or shall I set sendy.ambee.app → 157.230.9.219 in `Registered hosts`
  ?

Is there anything specific I need to set in Digitalocean settings?

**------------ ↓ UPDATE (Dec 15, 2020) ↓ --------------------**

It seems that the problem is with Google Domains provider since I tried to test it out a different provider that I have and I created an A record for `sendy.ambeeapp.com ->157.230.9.219` and it works without any issue (try `http://sendy.tomasbaran.com` to see for yourself).

Another thing is that I can't change the default Google NS servers, since I'm hosting Google Workspace on my main domain `ambee.app`.

Comment: It seems the issue is with the Google Domain provider. I tried to test it out a different provider that I have and I created an `A record` for `sendy.ambeeapp.com ->157.230.9.219` and it works without any issue. So, I don't know what's wrong with Google Domains but it looks like a problem on their end. I don't know what to do about it, though. First, I guess, I'll just have to wait 48 hours... which seems like eternity...

Answer (score 0):

To answer, succinctly, you want to add a custom Address mapping (`A`) record from the host name (`sendy`) to the IPv4 address (`157.230.9.219`) for your domain (`ambee.app`).

You should leave the name servers as they are; this configuration is necessary so that Google can manage your domain and resolve your records.

It's good to leave the defaults TTL but you can reduce these. Alternatively, once you've updated your DNS records through Google, you can check the resolver on Linux using either of the following:

```sh
nslookup sendy.ambee.app 8.8.8.8
nslookup sendy.ambee.app 8.8.4.4
```

> **NOTE** `8.8.*.*` are the IPs for Google's DNS service and will resolve quicky

It may (!) take some time (but usually not very long) for these updates to be shipped to other DNS resolves on the Internet.

It's unclear how you're able to resolve `sendy.ambee.app` to the IPv4 address (`157.230.9.219`) *without* changing your DNS records.

It's unlikely Google Domain's (i.e. Google's) DNS is at issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I agree with you that it's unlikely Google Domains service is at issue but that's what it appears like. I did exactly what you said (I set A record and left NS as they were) and 24 hours have already passed and it's still not working. I also tried`nslookup sendy.ambee.app 8.8.8.8` and this is what is showing `Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: sendy.ambee.app
Address: 157.230.9.219`
So, from terminal it looks like it's showing the correct IP.

Comment: IDK if you saw my comment below my question but for comparison I set A records on a different service than Google Domain and it's working well: HTTP://sendy.tomasbaran.com or HTTP://sendy.ambeeapp.com