# Setting up a sub-domain on Digitalocean

Tags: reactjs, web, subdomain, digital-ocean, droplet

How do I set up a **sub-domain** for a **Reactjs** website on **Digitalocean** using droplet?

Comment: Maybe your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264598/how-to-setup-subdomain-for-digitalocean

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you already have a domain set up:

First make sure you have the droplet up and running.

Then under Networking tab, go to Domains. Choose your domain, let's say "example.com"

Then you will be presented with the "create a new record" screen. There you add a new A record.

Type in there the full path, for example "demo.example.com" as hostname. And then choose the droplet you just created from the "will redirect to" dropdown. Click "create record" and you're done.